# Остановка сервера IIS из cmd

Tags: windows, веб-сервер, iis

Как из командной строки остановить сервер IIS так чтобы при возникновении ошибки интернет-службы не останавливались принудительно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если после остановки понадобится и запуск, то используйте `iisreset` без параметров.

Если только остановить, то `iisreset /stop`

Comment: кстати, iisreset без параметров всегда останавливает сервер, но запускает его только если тип старта сервиса - automatic. так что с ним стоит быть осторожнее.